# Changing background image of logon screen programmatically?

Tags: windows-7, background, authentication

I'd like to replace the bitmap on the logon screen of Windows 7 64-bit with one that is on disk. I have a program that periodically switches the background image of my desktop, and it has a configuration to run a program after it has changed it, which I thought I could use to also copy the same bitmap to the logon screen.

Does anyone know how to do that, or even if it is possible? If someone knows a handy command line utility to do it, that would of course be nice (but then I suspect this question should be migrated to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) first), but if someone has some API commands that would help, that would be more than enough.

I found an article which detailed a dll and some resources I would have to replace. That sounds a bit too hackish for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typed "[change background image logon screen windows 7](http://www.bing.com/search?q=change+background+image+logon+screen+windows+7&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC)" into a search engine and the first link was: [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-7-lets-you-change-the-logon-background-image/) which seems to show how to do it.  Now you just need to figure out how to write a program to automate the steps.